# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner con restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Tengo que hacer el @test al restTemplate y me rechaza la conexión, pero el servicio si lo ejecuto con SpringBoot funciona perfectamente, he hecho un microservicio que consiste en preguntar a otro microservicio por el listado de usuarios:

Api:

```
@GetMapping(value ="/usuarios")
public ResponseEntity<String> usuarios() {
    return this.service.usuarios();
}
```

Implementación:

```
    String resultado = this.restTemplate.getForObject(this.url, String.class);
    log.info(" ---> LogInfo: Ejecución correcta.");

    log.info(" ---> LogInfo: TERMINA el método");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultado, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Al hacer el test de la implementación he pensado que en vez de llamar al endPoint que me va a devolver los usuarios, voy a intentar llamar a mi propio servicio.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void testUsuarios() throws Exception
    {
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

          final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/usuarios";

            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, String.class);

            //Verify request succeed
            Assert.assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCodeValue());
    }
}
```

Lo hago de esta manera porque como la implementación solo tiene el restTemplate, me da igual llamar al servicio que me devuelve los datos o a mi propio servicio.
El problema es que me sale el error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/usuarios": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:323)
    at es.santander.mrpa.ApplicationTests.testUsuarios(ApplicationTests.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:687)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo suguiere [esta tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), puedes hacer uso de `MockMvc` para simular llamadas a tu controller.

Tomando tu test, y asumiendo que tu controller original se llama `MiControllerDeUsuarios`, deberia quedar algo asi:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = {MiControllerDeUsuarios.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTests {
    private static final String GET_USERS_PATH = "/usuarios";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testUsuarios() throws Exception {
          final ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(GET_USERS_PATH))
              .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```